# Creating Multiple Dynamic dropdown array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create a series of drop downs that are dynamically created based on the choice of the primary drop down.  The data is pulled from an array and I can do this if it's just two drop downs, but if I try to add a third drop down either only one or the other is dynamically created.

Here is what I have in my HTML:

```
Area: <select id="Area"><option label=" "></option></select>
<br />
Section: <select id="Section"><option label=" "></option></select>
<br />
Info: <select id="Info"><option label=" "></option></select>
```

Here is the script and array in my JS file:

```
//Dynamic Section dropdown created based on Area choice selected

// Areas List Array

var Area_arr = new Array(
"North",
"Central",
"South"
);


// Sections List Array

var Section_a = new Array();
Section_a[0] = "";

Section_a[1] = "Section 1|Section 2|Section 3|Section 4";

Section_a[2] = "Section 5|Section 6|Section 7|Section 8";

Section_a[3] = "Section 9|Section 10|Section 11|Section 12";


// Calls function to generate drop downs using options above

function populateAreas(AreaElementId, SectionElementId) {

// given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts 
<option> tags
var AreaElement = document.getElementById(AreaElementId);
AreaElement.length = 0;
AreaElement.options[0] = new Option('', '');
AreaElement.selectedIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < Area_arr.length; i++) {
    MAElement.options[MAElement.length] = new Option(MA_arr[i], MA_arr[i]);
}

// Assigned all Areas. Now assign event listener for the Sections.

if (SectionElementId) {
    AreaElement.onchange = function () {
        populateSections(AreaElementId, SectionsElementId);
    };
}
}

//Populate Sections once Area has been choosen
function populateSections(AreaElementId, SectionElementId) {

var selectedAreaIndex = document.getElementById(AreaElementId).selectedIndex;

var SectionElement = document.getElementById(SectionElementId);

SectionElement.length = 0;
SectionElement.options[0] = new Option('', '');
SectionElement.selectedIndex = 0;

var Section_arr = Section_a[selectedAreaIndex].split("|");

for (var i = 0; i < Hub_arr.length; i++) {
    SectionElement.options[SectionElement.length] = new Option(Section_arr[i], Section_arr[i]);
}
}
```

At the bottom of my HTML page I call the above function with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">populateAreas("Area", "Section");</script>
```

I tried to add a third drop down that has choices based off the First drop down called Area, however when I try to duplicate the code and call Area variables to get the list to display I won't populate.

I tried copying the section to just populate the Areas and duplicate it but it switches the data to the third drop down.

The choices in the Third drop down are not dependent on the Section drop down, just the Area drop down only.  So once you choose the Area, you can choose the Section drop down or the third drop down in any order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just a bit of a scrub by saying this but,  are you not talking about using a two dimensional array? ,  if so use:

Let  items = [ [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6] ]; console.log(items[0][0]); // 1 console.log(items);

If not,  that's fine,  I'll retract this answer,  however for some strange reason I am unable to find a reply button to your question,  so I will stick to just an answer.

Anyways,  good luck man,  sounds easy though,  probably right under your nose.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something but i've been scratching my head at this one.  Essentially what I'm doing is this.  I am using JS to create three drops downs.  The first drop down is the Primary while the other two drop downs have options that vary depending on which option from the first drop down is chosen.

So I have drop down A and I choose Area North.  by choosing this Area Drop down 2 will give 3 or 4 different sections, drop down 3 will give me names that belong to that specific Area.  If I choose Area South, then the drop down for Section and drop 3 will give me different results.

Comment: Omg that's so easy,  I think your over complicating it,  are you new to js,  and did you just finish a code course for js? .  If not w/e but nice to know :)   anyways Id just create a list of objects that you want in your final drop down and create an array that holds other arrays.  Example: Let menue2=[]; menu1.push(versionofmenu2) then at that step push objects to the second arrays like so(in loop)/initialization : menue1.myspecificmenue.push(object)

Then to access the objects once placed would look like menu1[0][0]

Comment: - (0 being the first array, second  0 the first object of that array) 

If you need a dynamic version that is a bit more complicated and requires non specific indexing,  you will need some indexing method like guid(), combined with a for loop to find the proper indexed objects for your condition.  If this did not answer your question,  please maybe give me your email or join me on discord and we can solve this externally and close this thread fast @ https://discord.gg/Rm6E2jD